# show a span before a json function executes

Tags: jquery, json, toggle

i have a search button on click of which i want to show 'searching' text till the search completes. so for this searching text i have a span which contains the text searching
now on click of button i am unable to show the span, as the control seems to be running to finish the json function

```
<span id="searchWait" style="display:none">&nbsp;Searching...</span>

<script>
function getPromptSearchResults() {
    $('#searchWait').toggle();

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'Application.aspx/getPromptSearchResults',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            some parameters
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#searchWait').html('done');
            something
        },
        error: function (parameters) {
            something
        }
    });

    return something;
}
</script>
```

Interesting fact is if i give an alert after the line $('#searchWait').toggle();
it shows the text searching and an alert, but if i click ok the alert will remain till the function has completed successfully. The html of span is changed correctly after search is completed.
Cant understand this weird behaviour in IE 8

Answer (score 0):

Try `show()` instead of `toggle()`.

Comment: already tried. doesnt work. all this works only if alert is added after the statement. That too alert also hangs if u click ok until the json function has executed.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to change span css as toggle depend on jquery events

```
function getPromptSearchResults() {

            $('#searchWait').css('display','block');

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'Application.aspx/getPromptSearchResults',
        data: JSON.stringify({            some parameters        }),
        success: function (data) {
$('#searchWait').html('done')
            something        },
        error: function (parameters) {
            something        }
    });

    return something;
}
```

Comment: already tried. doesnt work. all this works only if alert is added after the statement. That too alert also hangs if u click ok until the json function has executed.